# What happens when assigned something to a slice of a list on python?

Tags: python-3.11

```
li = [1,1,1]
li[:][0], li[:][1], li[:][2] = (0,0,0)
print(li)
```

The result of the above code is [1,1,1], and

```
li = [1,1,1]
li[:] = (0,0,0)
print(li)
```

The result of the this one is [0,0,0].

What makes this difference?:'

As far as I know, the slice of Python list data type was a copy of the original.
I've always thought so because the result of the code below was False, and so far, I've had no problem writing Python code.

```
li = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
li_s = li[:]
li_s is li
```

-> False

So I can't understand the result of the second code block.
Also, whether what I thought was a copy was right or wrong, why the results of the first and second code blocks are different?

It's actually the first time I've assigned something to a slice of a list.
I've never put a slice of the list on the left side of the symbol '='.
Maybe that's why I'm mistaken about something??